# Unable to pass props correctly to react-countdown component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using the package react-countdown and I am hoping to pass in a prop and use that prop as the initial state of of my timer variable. Then in turn pass the timer variable to the Countdown component.

```
const Location = (props) => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState([props.match.params.time]);


 return (
        <div>
         <h1>{timer}</h1>
         <Countdown date={Date.now() + {timer}} />
```

However when I run my code I get a NaN:NaN:NaN:NaN in the countdown. I am assuming that the timer in JSX is not in a type that can add to Date.now()! I can see that the timer value is rendered in h1 so I am confident that the state is getting set correctly.

I have tired to pass the timer to a parseInt() function but still having no luck.

Any suggestions!

Comment: what is ```console.log(props.match.params.time)``` returning?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove curly brackets around timer in `<Countdouwn/>`
like this :

```
const Location = (props) => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState([props.match.params.time]);


 return (
        <div>
         <h1>{timer}</h1>
         <Countdown date={Date.now() + timer} />
```